# 7-sphere x 4-sphere manifold and its physical significance

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, smooth-manifolds

I am looking for sources about this manifold 7-sphere*4-sphere and its relations to theoretical physics.

Where to go to read about 7-sphereX4-sphere manifold and its physical significance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you don't really mean for both spaces to be spheres, so I will interpret your question about the (4,7) split.  The context here is eleven-dimensional supergravity and the studies of such geometries date from the time (predating M-theory) of "Kaluza-Klein supergravity", when eleven-dimensional supergravity was of phenomenological interest.  A good place to read this, albeit written for physicists, is the Physics Report "[Kaluza-Klein supergravity](https://doi-org.ezproxy.is.ed.ac.uk/10.1016/0370-1573(86)90163-8)" by Duff, Nilsson and Pope.

The name of the game back then was the construction of solutions of the (bosonic) field equations of eleven-dimensional supergravity.  The dynamical fields are an eleven-dimensional lorentzian metric and a closed 4-form, satisfying equations reminiscent of Einstein-Maxwell theory, except that the Maxwell-like equation is nonlinear, reflecting a Chern-Simons term in the action.

Solutions were sought where the metric is (at least locally) a product of a four-dimensional lorentzian metric and a seven-dimensional strictly riemannian metric.  The idea being that the four-dimensional lorentzian metric is to be interpreted as the metric in our physical spacetime and the seven-dimensional riemannian metric is that of an internal space, assumed compact and small, since it is not observed.  With such a split there is a natural (geometric) choice for the 4-form: namely the volume form of the four-dimensional lorentzian metric.  The first such solution was found by Freund and Rubin in [Dynamics of dimensional reduction](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(80)90590-0) and are now known as Freund-Rubin compactifications.

One may wonder why the initial interest in Kaluza-Klein supergravity.  In trying to geometrise the standard model of particle physics and unify it with gravity, it is natural to derive inspiration from the Kaluza-Klein idea of viewing pure gravity in five dimensions as unifying four-dimensional gravity and Maxwell theories.  In this context, the gauge group of the standard model ought to be realised as isometries of the higher-dimensional geometry.  The smallest dimension of a riemannian manifold in which the standard model gauge group, which is isomorphic to $\mathrm{SU}(3) \times \mathrm{SU}(2) \times \mathrm{U}(1)$, can act effectively and isometrically is $7$.  Since we live in a four-dimensional spacetime, this suggests that the minimum dimension we need is $4+7=11$, which coincidentally is the highest dimension in which we can construct a (Poincaré) supergravity theory.  This was the lucky coincidence which launched a thousand ships, so to speak.

Comment: Yes, I mean that the multiplication of both two spheres 7- and4-sphere.thank you for your answer

Comment: Well, the 4-sphere does not admit a lorentzian metric, so I am not sure in what other Physics context do you find this.  Can you give a reference?

Comment: @O’Farrill, I am sorry, being very slow to respond to your comment. It took me sometime to understand your point.

Comment: With respect to, given a reference in which physics context do I find this, no I don’t have one. This is why I’m asking for. It is just my undereducated opinion. The reason I chose 4-sphere, because I am imagining our seen universe as blackhole with 4-sphere’  surface as the horizon